# How does R run Quicksort

Tags: r, recursion

I am learning recursion in R by studying the quicksort algorithm.
I understand the algorithm, but don't know how R runs through the code.

In the following code, why does R run the codes between `print("!!!")` and `print("!!!right before return!!!")` twice?

```
cycle <- 1
quickSort <- function(vect) {

# Args:
#  vect: Numeric Vector

# Stop if vector has length of 1
if (length(vect) <= 1) {
print(paste("cycle", cycle))
print(vect)
cycle <<- cycle + 1
return(vect)
  }
  # Pick an element from the vector
  element <- vect[1]
  partition <- vect[-1]
  # Reorder vector so that integers less than element
  # come before, and all integers greater come after.
  v1 <- partition[partition < element]
  v2 <- partition[partition >= element]
  print("before recursion, v1 and v2:")
  print(v1)
  print(v2)
  print("recursion begins")
  # Recursively apply steps to smaller vectors.
  v1 <- quickSort(v1)
  print("@@@")
  v2 <- quickSort(v2)
  print("!!!")
  print(paste("v1", v1))
  print(paste("v2", v2))
  print(paste("element", element))

  print("!!!right before return!!!")

  return(c(v1, element, v2))
}
quickSort(c(1,3,2,4,-2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints twice because it only takes 2 calls to sort the vector (2 that make it past the if statement). The print statements in this might help:

1st call it has sorted -2 & 1

2nd call it  has sorted 2, 3, & 4

```
cycle <- 1
quickSort <- function(vect) {
  if (length(vect) <= 1) {
    cycle <<- cycle + 1
    return(vect)
  }
  # Pick an element from the vector
  element <- vect[1]
  partition <- vect[-1]
  # Reorder vector so that integers less than element
  # come before, and all integers greater come after.
  v1 <- partition[partition < element]
  v2 <- partition[partition >= element]

  print("--------------------------------")
  print(c(v1, "-", element, "-", v2))

  v1 <- quickSort(v1)
  v2 <- quickSort(v2)
  return(c(v1, element, v2))
}

quickSort(c(1,3,2,4,-2))
# [1] "--------------------------------"
# [1] "-2" "-"  "1"  "-"  "3"  "2"  "4" 
# [1] "--------------------------------"
# [1] "2" "-" "3" "-" "4"
# [1] -2  1  2  3  4
```

This might help:

```
# first round (element =   1, v1 = -2, v2 = (3 2 4)) 
# second round (element =   1, v1 = -2, v2 = (element = 3, v1 = 2, v2 = 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Much clearer! Just to double check, the first recursive call gives (-2), which binds to v1. The second recursive call gives (2,3,4), which binds to v2. The element is 1 throughout the function. That's why we have the result, correct?

Comment: mostly correct, but you will have a second set of v1, element, and v2, when the recursive call is made on 3, 2, 4. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please see the edit above, hopefully it will clarify.